# Jabber id of a contact stored in iOS device

Tags: ios, xmpp

I want to send jabber id's of a contacts stored in my iOS device and by doing this want to check these jabber id's are registered at server.

But the problem what iam facing is with the country code.

In my contacts i have stored contact id with phone number as 8967905678 (i.e, without country code) .Generated the jabber id as 8967905678@myserver.com . But this user is already generated  an account with jabber id as +918967905678@myserver.com.

If this jabber id is already registered, i want to show this person information in my friends list. But because of country code iam not able to get this person info as already registered. 
Please help me out.

Appreciate your help in this regard.

REGARD,
BHAT

Comment: Take last 10 digits of contact number and jidStr and match them. that what i did in my chat application

Comment: Phone number # can not be always 10 digits(correct me if am wrong ), also user would have stored US/UK other country numbers as well without country code. In that case how to detect which country that contact belongs to ?

Comment: need to think that. Did u get the way to do that?

Comment: And did you get solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate Jabber ID with country codes. Take the country code of the user and add it to the phone number to get the full Jabber ID.
So in your instance if the messaging user is in India (+91 country code) then for all contacts without country codes prepend country code +91 and send it to server for searching.

This assumes all the users are stored on server with leading country code.

Strip the leading zeros and + signs.